# Magento. Why in admin grid the column is displayed always at the end even using addColumnAfter

Tags: magento

I created an Observer which adds a field to the newsletter grid in admin like this:

```
public function AddItemColumnToGrid($observer)
{
...
    if ($_type == 'adminhtml/newsletter_subscriber_grid') {

        $_block->addColumnAfter('subscriber_name', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Name'),
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'subscriber_name',
        ), 'subscriber_email');
    }
...
}
```

I cannot figure out. But Magento always displays my Subscriber_name field at the end (as the last in the order). ColumnAfter doesn't work. Why ?

I'm overring this:

```
        <events>
        <adminhtml_block_html_before>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the sorting happens before you hook into the HTML generation:

**Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid:**

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $this->_prepareGrid();             // <-- sort columns
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();    // <-- dispatch event
}
```

What you could do is sort again after adding the column:

```
    $_block->addColumnAfter('subscriber_name', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Name'),
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'subscriber_name',
    ), 'subscriber_email');
    $_block->sortColumnsByOrder();
```